# Download dependencies using serverless-python-requirements plugin on GitHub Actions throws "cannot find Python 3.7"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, github-actions

Here is my workflow: deploy.yml

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [develop, main]
env:
  name: project-name
  region: my-region
jobs:
  env:
    name: Load environment vars from .env files
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      <omitted>
  deploy:
    name: Deploy|${{needs.env.outputs.environment}}
    needs: env
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        id: creds
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}}
          aws-region: ${{needs.env.outputs.region}}
      - name: Setup python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: '3.7.7'
      - name: Installs Serverless plugins and Deploy
        uses: serverless/github-action@v1.53.0
        with:
          args: -c "serverless plugin install --name serverless-python-requirements && serverless deploy --verbose"
          entrypoint: /bin/bash
        env:
          SLS_DEBUG: '*'
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}}
          environment: ${{needs.env.outputs.environment}}
```

Here's my serverless.yml:

```
service: my-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.7

package:
  individually: True

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: false

functions:
  etl:
    name: ${env:environment}-etl-lambda
    handler: etl/lambda_functions/etl_lambda_function.lambda_handler
    module: etl/lambda_functions
    package:
      include:
        - ./etl
```

Project structure:

```
etl/
    lambda_functions/
        etl_lambda_function.py
        requirements.txt
```

Whenever the actions runs I get `Error: python3.7 not found! Try the pythonBin option.`

So I updated my serverless.yml to reference the python install in the opt/ directory (read more about that [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/guides/building-and-testing-python)):

```
custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: false
    pythonBin: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/bin/python3.7
```

But now I get `Error: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/bin/python3.7 not found! Try the pythonBin option.`

I am not sure how I can reference where `actions/setup-python@v2` installed Python, and reference that in `serverless-python-requests`

I have seen a few other questions on SO around serverless-python-requests, but none mentioning issues when running on GitHub actions.

I have also tried setting `dockerizePip: true` but I get `Errorr: cannot find docker` errors.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try replacing `python-version: '3.7.7'` with `python-version: 3.7`. Remove the quotes from the version. and in serverless.yaml, try with `runtime: python3` or `runtime: python` only and same in `pythonBin`. If possible add your gh actions build link in question as well.

Comment: Tried `python` as well as `python3` for `pythonBin` and got the same results. Also tried changing `python-version` as well but that made no difference. I don't think think `python-version` is the problem since the "setup python" step completes without errors. I think it has something to do with where the python executable is stored. I've also tried this path: `/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.7/x64/bin/python3.7` to no avail. It's a private repo so I can't share the build link.

Comment: There is possibly an error with your docker container and not the yml file. Or a disconnect in the Dockerfile with your yml. Dockerfile should have something like `RUN apt-get -qq upgrade -y python3.7` this is for Ubuntu. If you are trying to setup for the first time - you might be missing some environment setup.

Comment: @user923227 that makes sense! I get the error `E: Unable to locate package python3.7` when I add the above command as an arg in my `deploy.yml` but I think it's the right idea. I'll keep trying things in that direction.

Comment: I will update the comment as an answer.

Comment: @JacobRussell In which step in your GitHub actions does it fail?

Comment: @NoelLlevares `Installs Serverless plugins and Deploy`

Comment: I can't pinpoint what's wrong with your setup but I don't have this problem in this repo: https://github.com/dashmug/us-covid-stats even though I'm using GitHub actions, serverless-framework and serverless-python-requirements like you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is possibly an error with your docker container and not the yml file. Or a disconnect in the Dockerfile with your yml.

Dockerfile should have something like

```
RUN apt-get -qq upgrade -y python3.7
```

this is for Ubuntu. If you are trying to setup for the first time, you might be missing some environment setup.